# Faster or Bigger?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, fusion-drive

I had my question put 'on hold' because someone deemed it opinion oriented, so I'll rephrase it - For video editing, is it better to have a faster hard drive or a larger one? I hope to learn editing and am considering between a 512GB SSD and a 2 TBFusion. I think with the knowledge I'm looking for, it's not opinion.

I'm rephrasing the question because someone thought it was opinion based. This is starting to be useless in 3...2...1...

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate to your [other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/335879/88313).  You can edit the other question to make it on-topic but please don't create a new question.

Comment: You don't give enough information - so the answer is it depends

Comment: Well, I had my previous post put on hold because someone thought I was asking for an opinion. I think if there are 2 ways to do something, the one you choose is based on opinion.

Comment: Hi again. The crux of your question is *For video editing, is it better to have a faster hard drive or a larger one?* That question is still primarily opinion-based. For example, someone who only works on short 30 second videos will most likely say an SSD is better. On the other hand, someone who has to work with 50 hours of footage will probably say a larger hard drive is better. In other words, what is better for one person may not be better for someone else, and no-one here can say what is best for you without some clearly defined criteria.

Comment: Just some extra info: It's very easy to change/add external drives, but depending on your Mac model it's very hard (or impossible) to change your internal drive. So my *opinion* is still that going with an SSD for your internal drive is better overall.

Comment: @Robert Re: *"I think if there are 2 ways to do something, the one you choose is based on opinion."* Yes, usually based on some clearly defined criteria. The problem here is that your question isn't on topic for *this* site, because questions that are primarily-opinion based are off-topic. I encourage you again to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @robert - this is *inherently* an opinionated question becuase, to use an analogy, this is like asking "which is better, a Ferrari or a bus because to go from point A to B."  Without describing what your exact needs are (video editing is a broad description.  That said, memory and CPU are your main concerns unless you need lots of scratch disk access, but again, you must define this.

Comment: @monomeeth - Since I'm thinking about learning video editing, I don't know what to ask. Some here were kind enough to say that 'if you're doing x, then you'll need y. Problem basically solved, albeit having to go thru the hassle of overzealous mods. Don't worry - I won't be cluttering up your resources with further questions as I'll be taking my queries to a more user-oriented place.

Comment: @allan - Since I'm thinking about learning video editing, I don't know what to ask. Some here were kind enough to say that 'if you're doing x, then you'll need y. Problem basically solved, albeit having to go thru the hassle of overzealous mods. Don't worry - I won't be cluttering up your resources with further questions as I'll be taking my queries to a more user-oriented place.